# DataKeyValues are null in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datakey

Here is my `gridview` and the event that fires when a user clicks on the edit button within the row.  for some reason my `datakey` value is crashing the program saying it is null.  im not sure why.  the DataKeyNames in the `gridview` is exactly what I want it to be, `formID`.  this is correct because the last column in the `gridview`, as you can see, shows me the `formID` and it displays just fine.  so i have no idea where i am going wrong.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvHistory" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="5" 
                CssClass="userHistory" DataKeyNames="formID">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="clientName" HeaderText="User" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="formName" HeaderText="Form" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="dateCreated" HeaderText="Date Created" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="dateRevised" HeaderText="Last Revision Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="dateSubmitted" HeaderText="Date Submitted" />
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="edit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="editForm" 
                                Text="Edit" OnDataBinding="btnEdit_DataBinding" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="delete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName=""
                                Text="Delete" OnDataBinding="btnDelete_DataBinding" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="formID" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Session["formID"] = gvHistory.SelectedDataKey.Value;
    Label1.Text = Session["formID"].ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `CommandName` with your item template then You can simply use [Row_Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event, you don't need to create separate handler for button click.

```
protected void grdView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "editForm")
    {
      GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
      string value=grdView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["myDataKey"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.  this worked perfectly.  im sorry i even had to ask this question, end of semester, pressure mounting.  i should have been able to get this.

Answer (score 0):

Button btn = (Button)sender;

```
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        if (gvrow != null)
        {
            //Get the Row Index
            int rowIndex = gvrow.RowIndex;
            //Get the DataKey value
            Session["formID"] = gvHistory.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value.ToString();
            Label1.Text = Session["formID"].ToString();

        }
```